# Differential Equation power spectra

Tags: differential-equations

```
ε = .1; A = 0; ω0 = 1; ωf = 0; 
data = 
  NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == ε (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + A*Cos[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, 
    {t, 0, 100}];
Periodogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute", PlotRange -> All]
```

How would I create a suitable Power spectrum of the frequencies that this system has. For these set of values (at the top), there should ideally be only one unique frequency (ω0) since the other one is not in play.

Mathematica's example of power spectra utilizes the periodogram funcition, although I don't really understand what it does mathematically, so there is room for using another type of graph.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The code that gives me the best results is this.

```
ε = 3; A = 5; ω0 = 1; ωf = 1.788;
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == ε*(1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + 
    A*Sin[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 500}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Periodogram[Flatten[Table[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 500, 1}]], 
    PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute"]
```

Comment: Well, you could have mentioned the parameters are different ...

Comment: It's a completely different graph.

Comment: Yeah, because the conditions are different :D :D + There is a `Sin[$\omega ft$]` term in your answer whereas there's a `Cos[$\omega ft$]` in our code, based on the equation you provided in the first place. Obviously you made a lot of mistakes and you did not acknowledge making them.

Comment: Oh yes, I do agree that the forcing function is different, but it does not change anything in the output.

Answer (score 7):

```
ε = 1/10; A = 0; ω0 = 1; ωf = 0;
sol = NDSolve[{x''[
      t] == ε*(1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + 
      A*Cos[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, 
   x[t], {t, -100, 100}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, -100, 100}]
```

[image: function plot]

```
Periodogram[Flatten[Table[x[t] /. sol, {t, -100, 100, 0.5}]],PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: periodogram plot]

Answer (score 6):

Here's my shot at it:

```
ε = .1; A = 0; ω0 = 1; ωf = 0;

sol = First[NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == ε (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + A*Cos[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, 
    x, {t, 0, 100}]];
f = x /. sol;
data = Table[f[t], {t, 0, 100}];

Periodogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute"]
```

[image]

Comment: I've worked with this one, but it does not give me the correct results.

Comment: A-ha... And we should guess: Are there any error messages ? What do they say ? Any attempts to fix the "problems" ?

Comment: There are no error messages, the problem is that I am not getting a frequency on the x-axis, and the situations where I expect chaos, the power spectrum should be more messy.

Comment: Are you using the same code ? If not, please, do provide the code you are using.

Comment: Well, I've been trying it with yours, but there is no luck, and I tried with the other answer, but everything should be above the x axis.

Comment: As you can see I am using the _ScalingFunctions_ option with _"Absolute"_ property and everything is plotted above the _x_ axis. Do note, however, that using different step sizes when generating the table of values yields different results and the plots are really, really different.

Comment: @Slightly Just now I, once again, tested my code and I get the same results over and over. What is the set-up you are running _Mathematica_ on ?

Comment: I have been working with this for awhile, I haven't changed your code at all, I just think that I wasn't clear enough to what I wanted. I need the power spectra of the different frequencies that the system goes through. It has two unique frequencies in the differential equation (ω), but the way the entire thing operated can be chaotic. THe power spectra should show the ω that exist.

Comment: @Slightly I don't think that got any clearer. Please try to explain exactly what you want and why the suggested solutions fail in that respect. Best would be to update your post and show what you currently have and the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Before I do that, would you explain what exactly is plotted on the x and y axes on the periodogram above?

Comment: `Periodogram[list]` plots the squared magnitude of the discrete Fourier transform (power spectrum) of *list*

Comment: @Slightly Any progress ?

Comment: Sadly, no. I do not know how to get what I am looking for, and I do not know what I am doing wrong in explaining it.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the equation: $$\ddot{x} = (x,\dot{x},t)$$
The numerical solution generates a sequence of values of *x* at discrete values of *t*. This sequence is known as **time series**. Plotting *x* pk *t* might seem random or noisy, but often it contains harmonics at certain frequencies. Dominant frequencies in time series data can be investigated using the **Discrete Fourier transform**. For example we take *N* equally spaced values from the time series - $$x = x_{0},x_{1}, ..., x_{N}$$
The **Discrete Fourier transform** is defined as follows: $$X_{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N}x_{m}e^{\frac{-2\pi ikm}{N}},   (k=0,1,2,...,N-1)$$
Generally $X_{k}$ is a complex number. To analyse the frequency structure we analyse the **power spectrum** $P(\omega _{k})$ defined by: $$P(\omega _{k})=X_{k}\overline{X_{k}}=\left | X_{k} \right |^{2}$$

```
ε = .1; A = 0; ω0 = 1; ωf = 0;

ff = x[t] /. 
 First[NDSolve[{x''[
    t] == ε (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + 
    A*Cos[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, 
 x, {t, 0, 300}]][[1]]

Table[ff, {t, 0, 100}] // Fourier // Abs // 
 ListLogPlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I feel as if we are getting closer to the answer as I see you are using Fourier, although this isn't getting me the correct results. Here, there should only be one frequency at around .1.   Can you tell me what you are plotting on the x and y axes?

Comment: @Slightly Correct me if I am wrong, but this is the answer to your question. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: This is getting closer to what I am looking for, although the values are not correct. Since I have ω0 = 1, I should only have one peak at 1 (on the x axis)

Comment: I don't agree. Thanks for the help, though.